# ajax update textfield from database

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am new to ajax and i wanna ask a question that i tried to fix alot but couldn't figure out how. I have a html form which have 2 textfield areas. And i want to update second one from my database when user enter a value to first textfield.

I went through many online tutorials and i  myself wrote something like this:

html:

```
<tr>
    <td width="20"></td>
    <td width="229" bgcolor="#FCECEC">ID</td>
    <td width="319" bgcolor="#FCECEC">NAME</td>  
    <td width="82" align="left"><label>
        <input type="button" name="ADD" id="ADD" value="New User" onclick=" "/>
    </label></td>
</tr>
<tr>  
    <td bgcolor="#FCECEC" align="center">1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ID" id="ID" maxlength="11" onchange="showUser(this.value)"   value=" " /></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="40" name="NAME" id="NAME" maxlength="80" value="" /></td>
</tr>
```

ajax function:

```
function showUser(str)
{
    if (str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("NAME").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("NAME").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/myproject/users_update.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and a part of php side:

```
$q=$_REQUEST["q"];
$kps->WhatsId($q);
$tname=$kps->NAME;
$tsname=$kps->SURNAME;
```

When i do that i keep getting

> undefined index q

Where did i go wrong? Is it any true? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: your function name have a typo, showUser # Showuser

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($_REQUEST)` to see what are the parameters you receive?

Comment: yes i couldnt get the q as the parameter. İt returns null array. But I dont udnerstand why. Could you help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: can you add an alert on str in the first line plz?

Comment: try changing document.getElementById("NAME").innerHTML to document.getElementById("NAME").value.

Answer (score 0):

it is rather hard to know exactly what the problem is from the little information you provided.

like Bryan has mentioned you should change the `document.getElementById("NAME").innerHTML` to `document.getElementById("NAME").value`

but this is not what causing the problem.
in my opinion you got the url here wrong:
`xmlhttp.open("GET","/myproject/users_update.php?q="+str,true);`

but I can't tell for sure because I haven't seen you project directories